# What should I do to solve this cv2 error?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition

here is my code in python :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('human.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "image.py", line 10, in faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)  
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1689: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiMGQ.png)

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? What have you done to try to debug this? We can't do much, since we don't have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will guess but probably (as usually) you have to use full path to `.xml` files.

Without full path it searchs `.xml` in your current folder and it couldn't find them.

Luckly `cv2` has variable `cv2.data.haarcascades` with path to folder with `.xml` files.

On my computer `print(cv2.data.haarcascades)` gives

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/data/
```

So use `os.path.join()` to create full path.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(cv2.data.haarcascades, 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(cv2.data.haarcascades, 'haarcascade_eye.xml'))
```